# Magento - get the custom attribute value for products in an external PHP script

Tags: magento

does anyone know how I can get the custom attribute value for products in an PHP script (that we have in he root of the server which is used to generate XML an feed) ?

The custom attribute is property_type. Others work but not that one. Here is the code:

```
foreach ($arrayObj  as $row ) {
//get data
$pro_item = getPropertyItem($row['entity_id'],$pdo);
$images = getImages($row['entity_id'],$pdo);
$term = getTerm($row['entity_id'],$pdo);
$local=getLocation($row['entity_id'],$pdo);
// create tags and data
$item = $xml->createElement('item');
$i_status = $xml->createElement('status',getStatus($row['entity_id'],$pdo));
$i_propertyType = $xml->createElement('propertyType',$row['property_type']);
$i_title = $xml->createElement('title',htmlentities(removeAt($pro_item['title'])));

$i_projectName = $xml->createElement('projectName',getBuilding($local,$pro_item['title']));

$i_description = $xml->createElement('description',htmlentities(removeAt($pro_item['description'])));
```

Comment: What `$row['property_type']` contain ?

Answer (score 0):

My be below code will help you..!

```
$productId = 'YOUR PRODUCT ID';
$_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($productId);
echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Please try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Add your custom attribute `property_type` in the collection request with something like this :

*(before loop on result)*

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('property_type')
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add the below line in header part of script.

Mage::app('admin');

Set Used in Product Listing option to YES in admin panel attribute edit section.